# TYPO3: Wrap RECORDS if not empty or hidden in TemplaVoila

Tags: typo3, typoscript, templavoila

I have a field mapped in TemplaVoila as "container of elements" which generates some Typoscript in "Data processing":

```
10= RECORDS
10.source.current=1
10.tables = tt_content

# my new added wrap
10.wrap = <div class="someClass"> | </div>
```

Is there a way to make my new wrap depend on filling this container?
I need the same functionality as:

```
10 = TEXT
10.wrap = not empty: |
10.required = 1
```

**EDIT:** I managed to check if any content is in the container:

```
10= RECORDS
10.source.current=1
10.tables = tt_content
10.stdWrap.wrap = <div class="someClass"> | </div>
10.stdWrap.if {
 isTrue.field = field_contenttop
}
10.stdWrap.debugData = 1
```

It works but wraps container even if contents inside are hidden. I need to depend wrap on visible elements only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i guess stdWrap.required = 1 does the job.

```
10= RECORDS
10.source.current=1
10.tables = tt_content
10.stdWrap.wrap = <div class="someClass"> | </div>
10.stdWrap.required = 1
```